# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which I get from the form:

```
hobby = request.form.getlist('hobby')
```

The list is something like:

```
hobby = [sports, music, coding]
```

I would like to store this list in `mysql` server, so I have tried:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT into hobby(list,a_id) VALUES(%s,%s)', (hobby, current_user.id))
return '<h1> Inserted </h1>'
```

Comment: Very nice. What is not working?

Comment: Would it kill you to write a title that has more than 3 words and explains your problem concisely? (It's mentioned in the tour you seem to have gone through)

Comment: its showing TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: anoy.nmous ... please add the error message into the body of your question - NOT inside comments.

Comment: Do not call variables `list`, it overrides the `list` class reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`cursor.executemany`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) takes as second parameter an iterable of iterables. Every item will map to one time you execute the query. Every item then contains an iterable that contains the parameters to fill in.

So for this case, we should construct it like:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT into hobby(list,a_id) VALUES(%s,%s)',
                   [(interest, current_user.id) for interest in interests])
```

> **N.B.**: do not call variables things like `list`, since you will override the reference to the builtin `list` class. Here we named the list `interests`.